# Can’t delete Marketplace custom message

Tags: facebook-marketplace

Somehow a message I sent to a seller on Facebook Marketplace has been saved as my ‘custom message’, and pops up in the message field every time I open a listing. Although I have found it in settings, it won’t allow me to delete it. It’s annoying because it pops up over photos every time I open listing, and it was to a specific person about a specific post. How do I delete it? And can FB stop making the message field pop up over pictures - it is unnecessary and very irritating.